# registration form cakephp, mvc

Tags: php, cakephp, user-registration, cakephp-model

I'm new to cakephp framework and MVC concept. Below I've posted my MVC design pattern. I think I've made lot of mistakes here. `http://localhost/www/cakephp/app/View/Users/` When i use this link I can see my registration form. I don't know how to redirect to another page. 1st step only working (view reg form). Then how to redirect to another page? Clear me my mistakes here. I know i've made lot of mistakes. Anyone tell me with some clear explanation?

Model/User.php

```
App::uses('Model', 'Model');

class User extends AppModel {
     var $name = 'User';

    function register()
    {
     $name = $_POST['name'];
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     $password = $_POST['password'];
     $username = $_POST['username'];

         try
         {
             $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ( Name, Email, Password, Username, CreatedOn ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW() )");
             $conn->errorInfo();
             $stmt->bindParam('1', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
             $stmt->bindParam('2', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
             $stmt->bindParam('3', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
             $stmt->bindParam('4', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
             $result = $stmt->execute();
         } 
         catch (PDOException $e) 
         {
             'Error : ' . $e->getMessage();
         }
    }     
}
```

View/App/view.ctp

```
<html>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <p>Please fill out the form below to register an account.</p>
        <label>Name:</label><input type="text" name="name" size="40" />
        <label>Email:</label><input type="text" name="email" size="40"/>
        <label>Password:</label><input name="password" type="password" size="40" maxlength="255" />
        <label>Username:</label><input name="username" size="40" />
        <br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" />
    </form>
</html>
```

Controller/UsersController.php

```
<?php
class UsersController extends AppController
{
    public function register()
    {
        if (!empty($this->params['form']))
        {
            if($this->User->save($this->params['form']))
            {
                $this->flash('Registration Successful','/users/register');
            }
            else
            {
                $this->flash('Not succeeded','/users/register');
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

CakePHP documentation has a very useful [tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html#adding-posts)

The example is about adding posts, and it's very easy to adapt to what you need.

- In the model, you can just use the `save` function.
- In the controller, you can use `this->request->is('post')`, instead of checking if `$this->params['form']` is not empty,
- The form can be generated using the `FormHelper`